# C# Code is not working without breakpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, breakpoints

hello everyone my this code is working when i add breakpoint at this function. But when i run it without breakpoint then it is not working please tell me why it is happening.my this code is online when i run this code on localhost with a breakpoint then it is working fine but without breakpoint is show me not desired result

```
private void GetArticles()
{
    int RowCount = 0;
    sSQL = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tblArticle WHERE Status='Active'";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connection))
        {
            RowCount = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        }
    }

    sSQL = "SELECT TOP 3 Aid, Title, ArticleImage, LEFT(Description, 240) FROM tblArticle WHERE Status='Active' ORDER BY newid()";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connection))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            int cnt = 0;
            string divname = "book_hotel";
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string Url = "ViewArticle.aspx?aid=" + reader[0].ToString() + "&Article=" + reader[1].ToString();
                string FinalUrl = GetContextualURL(Url, reader[1].ToString());
                if (FinalUrl.Contains("'"))
                {
                    FinalUrl = FinalUrl.Replace("'", "^");
                }

                if (cnt == 0)
                    divname = "book_hotel";
                else if (cnt == 1)
                {
                    divname = "book_car"; 
                }
                else if (cnt == 2)
                {
                    divname = "book_cruise";
                }

                String p = "<div id='" + divname + "'>" +
                            "<h3>" + reader[1].ToString() + "</h3>" +
                            "<img src=" + reader[2].ToString() + " alt='article' height='140px' width='320px' />" +
                            "<p align='justify' style='width: 320px'>" + reader[3].ToString() + "....." +
                            "</p>" +
                            "<div align='right' style='width: 320px'>" +
                            "<a href='" + FinalUrl + "' class='more'>more</a>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "</div>";

                ArticleLinks.InnerHtml += p;
                cnt++;
                if (cnt == 4)
                {
                    ArticleLinks.InnerHtml += "</tr><tr>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "Not working",  what result do you get? what result are you expecting?

Comment: Do you mean when you deploy it to a server is does not work?

Comment: I think your question is totally fun . How is this possible ?

Comment: are you getting any exceptions or errors?

Comment: Where you put your breakpoint? And what you mean with not working exactly?

Comment: As a side note: you have some missing `using` (on the reader), you are doing string concatenation in a loop (inefficient), and it looks very much like you have XSS vulnerabilities (no html escaping / encoding). But **for here**, please define "not working" and "not desired result"

Comment: have you try clean and re build your solution?

Comment: @BenRobinson see i need three articles on  my page but i got sometime two articles and some time one articles but not exact three articles but when i put breakpoint evertime then i got exact three articles that i need

Comment: May be you are doing some background operation which is necessary for this to work correctly . When you put breakpoint that background process gets completed and in result it shows correct results , without breakpoint this code executes before that background process.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question , that is your code are only working on putting  breakpoint ?if remove the breakpoint then it's not working.

> if yes , Check your debugging mode , Set debug mode in locally and set release mode when deploy server .
>
> but ' it's not possible , I think it's any  silly problem , delete your obj folder and run . or close your visual studio ,reopen your application , then Check .